# How do I remove apache installed with make install and use apache from the repositories?

Tags: apache2

I want to completely remove apache from Ubuntu 11.10. I have installed httpd-2.2.22 package through `make` and the `make install` command. Now I want to uninstall it and install through `apt-get`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try `make uninstall` ?

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg`, `apt-get` et. al., don't know about the files in the `httpd-2.2.22` package, so they can't get rid of them.

Go back to the source directory, and see if `make uninstall` will do the trick. If not, or if you no longer have the source, there's a more complicated way.

Install the `installwatch` program, part of the `checkinstall` package (`sudo apt-get install checkinstall`).

If necessary, re-fetch the source, re-configure it the same as before, and rebuild it. If you still have the source directory you installed from, you can skip this step.

Then, `installwatch -o installwatch.log sudo make install` will generate a list of all the files the `make install` installed. These are the files you need to delete to erase the manual `httpd-2.2.22` install.