# how to remove httpd built from source

Tags: apache2, compiling, make

I'm aware of the post: [How do I remove apache installed with make install and use apache from the repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102156/how-do-i-remove-apache-installed-with-make-install-and-use-apache-from-the-repos).

I installed `httpd2.4` from source.  But for `httpd2.4`, there is no `make uninstall` available.  Are there any easy ways to purge `httpd2.4` built and installed from source?